# Inheritance or composition in object oriented design

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, composition, design-principles

I have seen many class diagrams on popular websites and design courses defining the relationships using composition like:
Admin has a person instance
Umpire has a person instance

As per me, shouldn't it be the case of inheritance as admin 'is-a' person, umpire 'is-a' person.
Admin extends Person
Umpire extends Person

Can you please help me understand why we are preferring composition here?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Composition is always favored over Inheritence. Except for the times you want to override methods of the superclass.

I believe there are two reasons for that.

- You can use only one class for extending so you will have more options for later on when using the composition.
- The principle for encapsulating. What you want is to encapsulate data as much as you can. You don't want to make the `Umpire` class inherit from Person just for the sake of accessing `Person`'s attributes. Inheritance usually implies that you want to override a method to use polymorphism and different behaviors for different subclasses. If you want to access a class's data you'll usually do it with an association or in case you want persistent data you'll use composition.

That's why you use composition when talking about `Umpire` and `Admin` classes since they don't change the behaviors of the `Person` class even though there's a noticeable 'is-a' relationship.